# Wrong param/query values in next.js SSR context

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, server-side-rendering, cloudflare

### This is my next.js directory structure for dynamic routes.

[image]

I am using params like this in my product page Server Side (SSR) :
[image]

I am getting correct values most of the time but sometimes productId returns the image name with extension (.jpg, .png, or even oEmbed).
Here are my logs of SSR:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is suffering from the same issue. It was not an issue with next.js or with any other service we were using. It was a bing bot that was doing wrong indexing.
Hope it helps.